# NSIS concatenate string with slash

Tags: string, variables, nsis

I'm trying to build a string with this expression `bla://${foo}/bar` where `${foo} == "hostname"`. The expected result is `bla://hostname/bar` but I get `http://${foo}/bar` instead.
So I figure there is something special about the combination `/$` but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't you have some warnings at the end of the compile log? is foo a variable or a define? Could you post the lines of codes where you build the string ?

Answer (score 2):

`/$` is not special but a define that does not exist ends up as `${definename}`.

```
DetailPrint "${foo}" ; Prints ${foo}
!define foo example.com
DetailPrint "${foo}" ; Prints example.com
```

All defines are resolved at compile time, if this hostname is something the user could configure on a custom page you need to use a NSIS variable...